# How do I lick a plane?

Tags: achievements, goat-simulator

A friend of mine told me that I would get an Achievement if I managed to lick the plane that's flying around in the world but, he won't tell me how to get close to it.

I tried many different things. Jumping on trampolines won't get me high enough, and the only thing that looks high enough is the crane, but I somehow can't jump that far when the plane (or... glider? I don't actually know what it really is.) shows up there.

How can I lick that thing, and what is the achievement I can get from it?

Comment: You know, when I saw videos and ads for this game on reddit, I seriously thought it was some kind of large 'meme' or joke of some kind. The concept of this game being real blows my mind.

Comment: This is exactly what I expected when I clicked on a question called "How do I lick a plane?"  I'm not even mad.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on Aviation SE, which deals with plane-licking.

Comment: It's not just Aviation SE. Code golf: *In as few characters as possible, lick a plane.* Code review: *Is my plane licking good enough?* StackOverflow: *I liked a plane, but didn't get the lick-a-plane achievement. What am I missing?* Programmers: *Is licking a plane an antipattern?* Workplace: *My boss circulated a memo restating the company policy against plane-licking. Should I quit now, or in two weeks?* DIY: *Not a hand plane?* … etc

Comment: @Jamal no, they *like* planes, not *lick* planes!

Answer (score 123, accepted):

[Here](http://www.videogamesblogger.com/2014/04/01/goat-simulator-achievements-guide.htm) are video guides for every achievement in Goat Simulator.
On the bottom of the page, you can find the "Mile High Club — Lick the Hanging Glider" achievement, which I think is the one you are looking for.

Same as you tried: you must climb up the big crane and then jump on the glider when it's close enough to lick it. It's [the last video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ub4elJoBN60). Watch at 0:30 to see how to perform the jump to reach the glider.